# Keep task running between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for few hints on a scenario with a Swift iOS project.

So I have a `Modal view controller` with `MKMapView`, I need this `Modal view controller` running while it's not the main viewing view controller, and it is dismissed. 
How would I keep it running and updated, while it is not the main viewing `view controller`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe more? why do you need to do this? Could you put a code snippet

Comment: @KhaledAnnajar I'm building this app with navigation functionality. And there's this feature where user would be able to dismiss the navigation `Modal View Controller` and wander around the app. Sorry, I don't have any snippet for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to keep a [strong reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) to the modal view controller,
Be careful to instantiate it only once, and check for its existence every time you have to show it.

Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mapVc:MapViewController? // strong reference here

    @IBAction func showMapVc() {
        if self.mapVc == nil {
            self.mapVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC") as? MapViewController
        }
        self.present(self.mapVc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func closeVc() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Marked as the correct. This is what I've been looking for. 
Would you please explain the logic behind this? and this `strong reference`.

Comment: Okay! I'm getting this. So what I think the `strong reference` instance loads the instance itself even before user put it to the main screen.

Comment: Awesomeness, Thanks!